# MongoDB array aggregation create new document query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have this array collection with

```
{
    "_id": 154,
    "title": "title1",
    "authors": [ { "name": "John Smith", "registered": true },
                 { "name": "Jane Doe", "registered": true },
               ],
    "tags": [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]
}
```

By using mongodb aggregation, I want to generate output like this

```
{
    "tag": "tag1", 
    "titles": [ "title1", "title2", "title3"], 
    "size": 3
},
{
    "tag": "tag2", 
    "titles": [ "title3", "title4" ], 
    "size": 2
}
```

Each tag should present with tag key.

I want to find all the tags which exists in other documents so that I can create separate array of titles, and at the very last size should show the length of the titles.

I am using this query, but I'm not getting the desired output

```
db.posts.aggregate([{$match:{"authors":{$all:[{$elemMatch:{registered:true}}]}}},{$unwind:"$tags"},{$project:{tag:"$tags",size:{$size:"$authors"},_id:0}}])
```

Can someone help me write the desired query?

I also tried

```
db.posts.aggregate([{$match:{"authors":{$all:[{$elemMatch:{registered:true}}]}}},{$unwind:"$tags"},{$project:{tag:"$tags",size:{$size:"$authors"},_id:0}}])
```

but I'm not getting desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need the `$group` operator. Are you looking for something like this?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "authors": {
        $all: [
          {
            $elemMatch: {
              registered: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tags",
      titles: {
        "$addToSet": "$title"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tag: "$_id",
      titles: 1,
      size: {
        $size: "$titles"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Given your sample document of:

```
  {
    "_id": 154,
    "title": "title1",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "registered": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "registered": true
      },
      
    ],
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ]
  }
```

The output is:

```
[
  {
    "size": 1,
    "tag": "tag2",
    "titles": [
      "title1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "size": 1,
    "tag": "tag3",
    "titles": [
      "title1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "size": 1,
    "tag": "tag1",
    "titles": [
      "title1"
    ]
  }
]
```

If I add another document of:

```
  {
    "_id": 153,
    "title": "title2",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "registered": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "registered": true
      },
      
    ],
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag3",
      "tag4"
    ]
  }
```

Then the output is:

```
[
  {
    "size": 1,
    "tag": "tag4",
    "titles": [
      "title2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "size": 2,
    "tag": "tag3",
    "titles": [
      "title1",
      "title2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "size": 2,
    "tag": "tag1",
    "titles": [
      "title1",
      "title2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "size": 1,
    "tag": "tag2",
    "titles": [
      "title1"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3pwNhueMYG7).

Comment: yes that will work
big thanks man I missed addToSet

Comment: Glad it worked! Please do accept the answer if it does the problem so that others know it's resolved